How to match a group exactly zero times
I am trying to match lines that do not contain a sequence of characters using sed. According to the sed documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), you use () in sed when using the ERE (-E option) to create groups and then {} to capture repetition of the preceding token. However, I want to match lines that do not contain this group (which also includes other things that I want to match).
Here is the contents of test_file:
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

These are just variations of the same line to test my sed command on. In essence, I want to modify lines that do not contain the path /home/tlytle/bin by appending :/home/tlytle/bin.
Here is my thought process as I am building up my ERE for sed:
First, I want to capture all lines that contain /home/tlytle/bin.
$ sed -E '\|/home/tlytle/bin| s|$|:/home/tlytle/bin|' test_file
Output:
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin

So far so good. sed appended :/home/tlytle/bin to the end of the only line that already contained :/home/tlytle/bin. Now, I want to create a group for that. So, I do this:
$ sed -E '\|(/home/tlytle/bin)| s|$|:/home/tlytle/bin|' test_file

Output:
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin

Still looks good. Now, just as a test, I want to match it 1 or more times. I could use a '+' here, but I want to test the repetition construct just ensure I am not losing my mind:
$ sed -E '\|(/home/tlytle/bin){1,}| s|$|:/home/tlytle/bin|' test_file

Output:
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin

Looks like it is functioning good to me. Now, I want this to match exactly zero of these. And this is where it breaks down:
$ sed -E '\|(/home/tlytle/bin){0}| s|$|:/home/tlytle/bin|' test_file

Output:
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin

It looks like the ERE matched every line. I would have thought it would have only matched lines that did not contain /home/tlytle/bin.
Can someone explain to me why this does not do what I think it should do? Is there some other ERE construct I should be using?

+ is the same as {1,}, * is the same as * but with 0 or more matches, also the same as {0,}. A ? would be the same as {0}. What are you trying to achieve? A ? or {0} means the previous search is not required to match so anything would be matched. I would run your regexs on regex101. That will generally show you what is being run. They dont have a POSIX engine though that I'm aware of. Are you trying to negate a /home/tlytle/bin match?

Use the ! operator after the regexp to process lines that don't match the regexp. E.g. /foo/!s/abc/def/ will do the replacement on all lines that don't contain foo.

Using GNU sed compare the results of <<<$'aabc\nxabc' sed -E 's/(aa){0}bc/ \&=& \\1="\1"/' to <<<$'aabc\nxabc' sed -E 's/(aa){0,}bc/ \&=& \\1="\1"/'

As others have said, just use a bang to fix your sed:
sed '\|/home/tlytle/bin|!s|$|:/home/tlytle/bin|' test_file

And if you have the concerns about special characters needing to be escaped, use perl and its ability to escape with \Q..\E:
perl -pe '$p="/home/tlytle/bin"; s/$/:$p/ unless /\Q$p\E/' test_file


Other way: write a pattern with two branches. The first one is the target that will be overwritten, the second one is the end of the line:
sed -E 's#:/home/tlytle/bin|$#:/home/tlytle/bin#' test_file

About the {0} quantifier: a group, a class or a single character with this quantifier describes an empty string (that succeeds every time, everywhere in the string and for all strings). It isn't a negation. Keep in mind that a pattern is a description, not a wish list.

sed is great for simple s/old/new on individual lines, for anything else just use awk, e.g. using any awk:
$ awk -v reqd='/home/tlytle/bin' '{print $0 (index($0,reqd) ? "" : ":"reqd)}' file
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

With that I'm storing the required path segment in a variable (-v reqd='/home/tlytle/bin'), then printing the current line (print $0) followed by a ternary expression within which I do a string comparison to see if that required string is already present (index($0,reqd)) and, if so, printing nothing else (""), otherwise print a colon followed by the the required string (":"reqd).
If your target string can contain backslashes then you need to pass it into awk using ENVIRON[] or similar, see How do I use shell variables in an awk script?, and if your target string could be a substring of some other input string that you do not want to match, e.g. /foo/home/tlytle/binary, then you'd need to tweak the code to handle that.
Regarding the code in your question, matching zero repetitions of anything will match any input whether that "anything" is present or not:
$ echo 'foo' | sed -En '/(bar){1,}/p'
$ echo 'bar' | sed -En '/(bar){1,}/p'
bar
$


$ echo 'foo' | sed -En '/(bar){0}/p'
foo
$ echo 'bar' | sed -En '/(bar){0}/p'
bar
$

so trying to do something by matching on zero repetitions of anything will always fail.
You can do what you attempted in GNU sed at least (maybe with others too, idk) with the ! (not) operator to test if the preceding regexp comparison failed:
$ echo 'foo' | sed -En '/(bar)/!p'
foo
$ echo 'bar' | sed -En '/(bar)/!p'
$

and then you can do this for your current problem:
$ reqd='/home/tlytle/bin'; sed '\#'"$reqd"'#!s#$#:'"$reqd"'#' file
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin
#Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/tlytle/bin
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/home/tlytle/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

but note that with the sed version, in addition to the considerations I listed below the awk script, you have to also hope there are no #s (or whatever other delimiter char you choose) or regexp metachars or backreference metachars in that string, see Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed because sed has no constructs to handle literal strings, unlike awk.
